# Cocos2d + UIViewController switch

Tags: uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone

Its a game with cocos2d 2.1 beta.

I used seperate viewController that comes when pressing button. When I fast switch between these two then some time game hangs...Not crash..fps label works. Something like stopAnimation..

What's wrong with my code? How can I avoid hang? Only when fast switched.

```
-(void)showNativeView
{
    UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [[app navController] presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{controller.view.alpha = 1.0;}];

    [controller release];
}

-(void)gotoGameAgain
{
    AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [app navController].modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [[app navController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to initiate the UIViewController when the button is clicked? It may be better if you initiate only once and than use it when the button is clicked. Initiating it evertime you clicked on the button may be creating some performance issues during the fast switch...

Comment: no..its not solution for me. Already game uses lots of memory and done lazy loading too. When I backup this view then lots of memory problem.

Comment: Here problem is not with loading time. OpenGL animation/Cocos2d animation not resume. something wrong with Cocos2d stop/start animation api.